# Adding H1 tag for SEo

Tags: php, joomla, seo, joomla2.5

[H1,H2 tag, SEO and google Adwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783569/h1-h2-tag-seo-and-google-adwords)

I have no idea how adding H1 to the webpage helps SEO but I am required to make my company website support SEO, and I am using Joomla 2.5. As many people say, h1 should only be used once on each page. I foolow steps by Joomla document to add a static text in php for page title. So I think now I just need to add

```
<h1> <?php some code to get page title 
</h1>
```

Is that enough for SEO support ?

Comment: `<h1>` tags are good for spiders because it allows them to see the hierarchy of information. Have a read of this for a good grounding on the various aspects of seo: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/search-engine-optimization-101/?search_index=4

Comment: [I haven't actually read through this, but it looks informative.](http://www.seomoz.org/beginners-guide-to-seo)

Comment: Thank you, there are many things about SEO now, I don't think I can add them all in my website within an hour. So I only would like to add h1, other things I would like to ignore

Comment: best not to "add then all" anyway -- Google actively punishes the rankings of sites that it thinks are over-doing their SEO efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea it is enough. Also you can use the other levels of heading tag to represent the sub-titles or the sub-pages.